# Responsive navbar dont appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I resize the screen, the bars icon don't appear on the screen whilst the ul disappear too i run it in codepen bu it doesnt work 
where is the problem ?
is it in the javascript, I've never used the language before

```css
@media (max-width: 960px){
  .toggle{
    display: block;
  }
  ul{
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
  }
  ul li{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .active{
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <div class="toggle">
        <div class="menu"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></div>
      </div>
      
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.menu').click(function(){
    
    $('ul').toggleClass('active');
    
  })
 })
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You had this code

```
<div class="toggle">
      <div class="menu"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></div>
    </div>
```

Inside the , which is being hidden with CSS by display:none. Take that code out of the  and it should work.

```css
@media (max-width: 960px){
  .toggle{
    display: block;
  }
  ul{
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
  }
  ul li{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .active{
    display: block;
  }
  .menu{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background-color:red;
  }
}
```

```html
  <nav>
    <div class="toggle">
      <div class="menu"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></div>
    </div>
    <ul>          
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.menu').click(function(){
    
    $('ul').toggleClass('active');
    
  })
 })
  </script>
</body>
```

Edited: I added some code to make the menu visible. The icon not appearing is not a problem of any of the code you provided, but some other issue. I think you're not importing a library or something.

Comment: It didnt work because when I resize my screen both the navbar and the bars icon disappear

Comment: Is this icon snippet copied from somewhere else? Because it seems like there is no code to show the icon anywhere in the first place.

Comment: https://codepen.io/oumaben/pen/OBPEYQ here is the code 
and my problem is that when i resize the screen the navbar and the bar icon disappear

Comment: @Lilas and what I am saying is that your icon is never there in the first place. You don't have any codes that populates the icon.